# ANSI-code of a whole word

Tags: hash

I am just starting to learn hashing in C. The task is to find hash-function of a word using ANSI-table.

I read something about hasing in the net and in theory I can understant it, but in practice i can't cope with it.

I find this piece of code, but I don't know how to find a ANSI-code of a WHOLE word (by addition of ANSI-code of each letter), but not a single latter. I try to use a for-loop to cope with it, but i didn't get a result.

```
 char *s="qwerty";
     while(*s!='\0')
      {
         printf("%c --> %d\n",*s,*s);
         s++;
      }
```

Thanks in advance for Your answers or any help.

Comment: It is correct: You are getting the ASCII code for all characters. Usually we use %02X to get hexadecimal digits. "ANSI code" is a misnomer probably related to Windows' naming of ASCII as ANSI

Comment: So, for a whole world you just display the word, then the arrow, then the %02X formatted ascii codes of each character, which may be separated by spaces

Comment: @PaulStelian  Yes, I am getting the ASCII code for all characters, but i want to **get  ASCII code for a word "qwerty"** by addition of ASCII code of every letter.

Comment: @PaulStelian it is not correct - printf("%s --> %02X\n",*s,*s); ? the result is (null) --> 00

Comment: Beware that %s takes the pointer (s) rather than the character (*s)